# How to keep branches separated in IntelliJIDEA?

Tags: git

I created 2 new branches from the master one. Let's say Branch A and branch B. When I do a checkout on Branch A and modify some files and the I checkout on Branch B (or the master branch) I can see the changes that I made on branch A in the branch B.

Basically I want to keep the two branches separated, so I can work in parallel on two different features. In that way, when I commit Branch B I don't commit al the changes that I made on Branch A.

How can I achieve that without commiting the branches?

Comment: Did you commit your changes to branch A before checking out the other branch?

Comment: if ur changes are not commited to branch A, they will remain even when u checkout to branch B.

Comment: Not I don't commited my changes before the checkout. Is not possible to keep them separated without commit? I don't want to commit partial changes when the test are  not running successfully. But maybe I need to work on the other branch because the other features had become more critical (for example)

Comment: One way is to clone the repo twice into two different directories, then open them as separate projects in IntelliJ. Check out a different branch in each project.

Comment: Don't be afraid to add broken commits to your local branches.  You can always squash them later with `git rebase -i`.

Comment: @DonBranson No need for two clones, you are describing a work-tree.

Comment: I totally agree with 0x5453, "I don't want to commit partial changes when the test are not running successfully" suggests a misunderstanding of what Git is. Or maybe you are confusing "commit" with "push"?

Comment: @0x5453, ok suppose that I have 3 commit that I want to squash before I push them on GitHub for example. So that I will have only one commit on Github. It is possible to use the intelliJ UI to do that without write git commands?

Comment: @SimoneGiusso Yes, it [looks like](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14608812/3282436) you can.

Comment: @matt - thanks! I'll have a look.

Answer (score 2):

You are describing `git worktree`.

https://git-scm.com/docs/git-worktree:

> A git repository can support multiple working trees, allowing you to check out more than one branch at a time